# Triple confirmation (not needed)

Tags: vbscript

I have added a confirmation dialog to a vbs script (provided by 3rd party) but I do not need to click the "OK" 3 times and would like the confirmation prompt to show only once... In my (limited) knowledge I do not manage to do that, can anybody kindly correct this code?

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

a = "C:\Path to file 1\File 1.txt"
b = "C:\Path to file 2\File 2.txt"

RenameItem a, a & ".bak"
RenameItem b, a
RenameItem a & ".bak", b

Sub RenameItem(oldname, newname)
  If fso.FileExists(oldname) Or fso.FolderExists(oldname) Then
If fso.FileExists(oldname) Then Set f = fso.GetFile(oldname)
If fso.FolderExists(oldname) Then Set f = fso.GetFolder(oldname)
f.Name = fso.GetFileName(newname)
  End If
Msgbox "Files were toggled successfully" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "(click the ""OK"" button to exit)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RenameItem()` is a [sub(routine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt223ahx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), i.e. a unit of code which can be reused. Every time you call the sub, it executes everything in it, including the `MsgBox`.

Move this line outside of the sub:

```
Msgbox "Files were toggled successfully" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "(click the ""OK"" button to exit)"
```

### Full Code

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

a = "C:\Path to file 1\File 1.txt"
b = "C:\Path to file 1\File 1.txt"

RenameItem a, a & ".bak"
RenameItem b, a
RenameItem a & ".bak", b

Msgbox "Files were toggled successfully" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "(click the ""OK"" button to exit)"

Sub RenameItem(oldname, newname)
    If fso.FileExists(oldname) Or fso.FolderExists(oldname) Then
        If fso.FileExists(oldname) Then Set f = fso.GetFile(oldname)
        If fso.FolderExists(oldname) Then Set f = fso.GetFolder(oldname)
        f.Name = fso.GetFileName(newname)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Tim: Thanks for the **amazingly** quick answer and for the (much appreciated) explanation :)